# Different views for each object in observableCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to use a WrapPanel. I have a ObservableCollection with ViewModels which all have its own view. Is there a way to use DataTemplates and use multiple views ?

This is what I am doing right now:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ProjectInfoDetailTemplate"> <!-- DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ProjectInfoViewModel} -->
        <views:ProjectInfoView MouseLeftButtonDown="ProjectInfoView_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AllProjects}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectInfoDetailTemplate}" Margin="0,15,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type views:ProjectInfoView}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
                        </Style>
                    </WrapPanel.Resources>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

But each item in the observableCollection AllProjects needs an own view.

How can you do this ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ItemTemplateSelector to provide correct templates for each item. Or you can create  DataTemplates without x:Key but with TargetType set and don't specify ItemTemplate on your ItemsControl. This way wpf will find correct DataTemplate itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not quite sure if it was possible to not define a ItemTemplate ;)